# AngularJS $promise is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am trying to make an ajax call using $resource and load a datatable upon receiving the data from a server. But when I call a get() then I am getting $promise as undefined.
I am using a factory to make the call.
Here is my factory :

```
    app.factory('getAllUsers', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('URL', {}, {get : {method : 'GET'}});
}]);
```

And the controller :

```
      app.controller('MyController',function($scope,$location,getAllUsers){

        console.log("In controller");

        getAllUsers.get().$promise.then(function(data) {

            loadDatatable(data);
            });


     });
```

ERROR : getAllUsers.get().$promise is undefined

NOTE : I have included ngResource in my app and angular-resource.js in index.html too.

Answer (score 1):

The `$resource` service doesn't return promises in version 1.0.x; be sure to read the correct version of the docs. By default, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ is for the 1.2.x series, which is currently unstable. Try this version of the api docs: http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `$resource` you can do

```
 getAllUsers.get({},function(data) {
    loadDatatable(data);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add .json as type of call?

```
app.factory "User", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/users/:id.json", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
]
```