# $resource and $promise returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, ngresource

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
```

on this code:

```
App.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Main', 'MainFilter', function($scope, Main, MainFilter) {
    $scope.scope_variable = Main.query().$promise.then( function(result) { MainFilter.do_something(result) } );
}]);

App.factory('Main', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/main_resource.json')
}]);
```

I've been trying to follow these other examples of using promise within the controller (I'm not using $routeProvider), but nothing seems to be working.

[AngularJS using $resource service. Promise is not resolved by GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008244/angularjs-using-resource-service-promise-is-not-resolved-by-get-request)

[AngularJS resource promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490560/angularjs-resource-promise)

Comment: Where are you defining `$promise`?

Comment: `Main.query({}, function(data) { console.log(data) })`

Comment: I was assuming that $promise was defined in $resource...

Comment: @tymeJV console logging the data returns the correct array of resources.

Comment: Why not use the snippet of code I provided then? Should have access to the returned data and all is golden

Comment: just did that.  Thanks!

$scope.scope_variable = Main.query({}, function(result) { MainFilter.do_something(result) } );

If you put the above in an answer I'll mark it accepted for ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tymeJV provided this answer:

$scope.scope_variable = Main.query({}, function(result) { MainFilter.do_something(result) } );